# How to add copy a whole column to an html table with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I want to create an html table inside an html form whose number of column depends of a variable that the user will enter. Here is an extract of the script I tough would work. Unfortunately, it does not.

```js
var nbrCofondateur = 5;
var nbrColonne = 2; 

function tabGenerateur()
{
 
while (nbrCofondateur>nbrColonne) {
  
 $("#col1").clone().appendTo("#col1").parent(); 
$("#col2").clone().appendTo("#col2").parent(); 
 
 nbrColonne++; 
}

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Calculatrice d'équité</h1>
  <p>Remplissez ce formulaire pour déterminer quel pourcentage d'équité chacun des co-fondateurs de votre start-up devraient recevoir.</p>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid" class="deuximeFormulaire">
<form>
 <table id="myTable">
  <tr id="cofondateursListe" >
    <th></th>
    <th>Cf 1</th>
    <th id="col1">Cf 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Quel est le taux horaire que le co-fondateur pourrait exiger sur le marché du travail?</td>
     <td><input style="width:100%" type="number" id="q1-cf1"></td>
      <td id="col2"><input style="width:100%" type="number" id="q1-cf2"></td>
  </tr>
 
</table> 
 <button type="submit" class="Submit" onclick="tabGenerateur();">Soummettre</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I might understand what you want. You dont have to put `parent()` after `append()` and also you should not have more than one element with the same ID which is exactly what you are doing by copying the elements.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki, isn't the title clear enough?

Comment: Your code isn't clear enough and doesn't reflect what you have in title.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("button").click(function () {
  $("tr > :last-child").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.clone().appendTo($this.parent());
  });
});
```

```css
table { width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; margin-bottom: .5em; }
table, tr, th, td { border: 1px solid; }
th:first-child { counter-reset: th, td; }
th { counter-increment: th; }
th:after { content: "Col " counter(th); }
td:first-child { counter-increment: td; }
td:after { content: "Row " counter(td); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr><th>A <th>B </tr>
  <tr><td>C <td>D </tr>
  <tr><td>E <td>F </tr>
</table>

<button>Add column</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I used it, but I have a small problem. The count of column begin at 1, but the first column is filled with descriptions, not with the actual elements, so I don't want to display anything above the first column. However, when I set the value of the counter to -1, all the column are listed as Col 0. Can you help?

Comment: @JulienBrault, the code doesn't use the counter - it's just a demonstration.